# UNION ALL and fill date column with NULL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=84fce212acaf7df65b7d6772e5dc50ba)**

```
CREATE TABLE sales (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    last_order DATE,
    customer VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO sales
(last_order, customer)
VALUES 
('2020-04-10', 'user_01'),
('2020-06-15', 'user_02'),
('2020-08-26', 'user_03');



CREATE TABLE customers (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    first_order DATE,
    customer VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO customers
(first_order, customer)
VALUES 
('2020-03-10', 'user_01'),
('2020-05-15', 'user_02'),
('2020-01-17', 'user_03');
```

**Expected Result:**

```
last_order   |   first_order     |
-------------|-------------------|----
2020-04-10   |                   |
2020-06-15   |                   |
2020-08-26   |                   |
             |    2020-03-10     |
             |    2020-05-15     |
             |    2020-01-17     |
             |                   |
```

In table `sales` I have the date of the `last_order` and in table `customers` I have the date of the `first_order`. 
Now I want to `UNION ALL` both tables and therefore need to fill the column `last_order` and - respectively - the column `first_order` with **NULL** to keep the structure equal.

In `postgresSQL` I am using this query which works without any issue:

```
SELECT
s.last_order AS last_order,
NULL AS first_order
FROM sales s

UNION ALL

SELECT
NULL AS last_order,
c.first_order AS first_order
FROM customers c
```

---

However, when I apply this query to `amazon-redshift` I get error:

```
Invalid operation: UNION types date and text cannot be matched
```

How do I need to modify the query in `amazon-redshift` to achieve the expected result?

Comment: Try cast NULL to DATE explicitly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Serg please try to cast null into date like below:

Query:

```
 SELECT
 s.last_order AS last_order,
 NULL::date AS first_order
 FROM sales s
 
 UNION ALL
 
 SELECT
 NULL::date AS last_order,
 c.first_order AS first_order
 FROM customers c
```

Output:

| last_order | first_order |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-04-10 | null |
| 2020-06-15 | null |
| 2020-08-26 | null |
| null | 2020-03-10 |
| null | 2020-05-15 |
| null | 2020-01-17 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=6dd31c56266c74d7be9a7dc08b0031ca)*

Answer (score 2):

An amusing way to do this is:

```
select s.last_order, c.first_order
from sales s full join
     customers c
     on 1 = 0;  -- never true!
```